# Azure Media Services - Can't connect to RTMP

Tags: rtmp, azure-media-services

I wanted to stream from my mobile device (iPhone 7 Plus / V14.1) with Larix and GoPro App to Azure Media Services:
rtmp://test-livestream-usso.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx70af

Both devices can't connect to the RTMP on Azure. When I tip the rtmp url into my OBS, it works perfect. Any idea what the issue could be here?

Bests,
Yanick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBS and a lot of encoders automatically add on a stream key at the end of the path.
Just add an additional /whatever after the GUID to make it work.

Also make sure you are not sending >30fps. We only accept up to 30fps 1080P.

BTW, my GoPro Hero 8 works just fine adding an additional stream key path after the ingest path GUID.

Comment: Works with Larix. Will test with GoPro, too. Thank you so much johndeu!